# I don’t know where to start with errors when attempting installation of open source UNCeqR on z shell

Tags: macos, open-source

The following error presented on macOS z shell during installation:

```
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 11.
not ok 1
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 2
  CALLAHAN/Math-CDF-0.1.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports CALLAHAN/Math-CDF-0.1.tar.gz
```

Do these compilation errors during installation or is it just a z shell error?

Comment: zsh is a POSIX shell and so like sh or bash thus I would suspect the build. I don't know CPAN but a guess is that you do not have make installed - for that install Xcode from the AppStore and then command line tools

Comment: If all the OP needs is `make`, then just install the CLT.

Comment: Huh.  Supported on Linux according to its GitHub page.  No mention of macOS.  But reading the installation instructions, `make` isn't missing.  It's failing when it tries to install `Math::CDF` from CPAN.

Answer (score 1):

pre-installation with conda package manager will be better than the direct `CPAN` command

> conda install -c bioconda perl-math-cdf

(direct CPAN command may not work in zsh,  `cpan INSTALL Math::CDF`)